# Ternary opeartor in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery and platform is Visual Code. And I'm a newbie in Mean Stack. I am using Ternary Operator for practice. I made a program, but it doesn't give me the output as I want. I'm not certain about the problem. I want the user to enter the age and give me output as done by the ternary operator. When I run cmd, it runs the program and print 'What's is your age' and shows me **ReferenceError: prompt is not defined.**

Can anybody tell me where I am wrong?

What I have tried:

```
var name = prompt('What is your age?');
console.log(name);
var age;
var voteable = (age < 18) ? "Too young":"Old enough";
```

Comment: When you run this in Node from the command prompt, there is no `window`, and no `window.prompt`, where do you expect to see the prompt. Also, `age` is never given a value, hence it's value is `undefined`

Comment: Single line answer: `var voteable = +prompt('age?') < 18 ? 'TY' : 'OE';`

Comment: @adeneo you're right. I changed my code.                                               `var age = window.prompt('What is your age?');
age = parseInt(age);
var voteable = (age < 18) ? "Too young" : "Old enough";
alert(voteable);`

Comment: I was going to say ternary operators makes code harder to read...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the ternary conditional, you're using a function called "Prompt" that doesn't exist in your environment

In a web browser, your code would work. It still wouldn't do what you want it to do because you don't assign to the right variables, but it would technically work

Comment: Ergo, how will it work, If I want to run it through cmd?

Comment: You'll need to provide more details on the environment that you're coding in before I can suggest an alternative. I can't find a Javascript environment that is just called "Visual Code". I suspect that you're trying to run node.js through Visual Studio Code, in which case I don't think there's a straight alternative to prompt

Comment: @wardahamk prompt won't in node environment but you can use node argv

Comment: @AkinjideBankole I want user-input, so I used prompt will, but didn't work.

Comment: @wardahamk You'll need to install a module to do it. The one suggested by Saroj Sasmal looks good

Comment: Yup @wardahamk you can try Saroj Sasmal suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like below,

```
var age = prompt('What is your age?');
console.log(age);
var voteable = (age < 18) ? "Too young":"Old enough";
alert(voteable);
```

OR

```
var age = prompt('What is your age?');
alert((age < 18) ? "Too young":"Old enough");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong in the code it will work perfectly fine in browser. Since your environment is different you are getting this error. If you really want to make this code work in  nodejs.

```
npm install prompt
```

This above command is for installing prompt in node.

```
var prompt = require('prompt');
prompt.start();
prompt.get(['age'], function (err, result) {
  if (err) { return onErr(err); }
  console.log('Command-line input received:');
  console.log("age" + result.age);
  var age =  parseInt(result.age);
  var voteable = (age < 18) ?  "Too young":  "Old enough";
  console.log(voteable)
 });

function onErr(err) {
  console.log(err);
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: the code seems hard. I used the ternary operator to make code easy and get rid off those if-else clusters. :(

Answer (score -1):

You need to define age and using ternary operator moreover I don't think prompt is available in that environment as **Andrew Pay** mentioned

```
var name = prompt('What is your age?');
console.log(name);
var age = parseInt(name);
var voteable = (age < 18) ?  "Too young":  "Old enough";
```

Comment: you cant use return like that in a ternary operator